# Saving images with Imlib2

Tags: c, image-processing, lua

I'm trying to save the same image twice using imlib2 but I keep receiving the following error message:

"bad argument #1 to 'save' (image has been freed)"

My Lua code:

```
imglib.save(img,"PATH1",false)
imglib.save(img,"PATH2",true)

imglib.save = function(img,outpath,freeImg)
    local _,err = img.save(img,outpath)
    if (freeImg) then
        img.free(img)
    end
    return err
end
```

My C code:

```
static int image_save(lua_State *L)
{
  Imlib_Load_Error err;

  Image im = check_Image(L, 1);
  imlib_context_set_image(im);
  imlib_save_image_with_error_return(luaL_checkstring(L,2), &err);

  if (err == IMLIB_LOAD_ERROR_NONE)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    lua_pushnil(L);
    push_load_error_str(L, err, luaL_checkstring(L, 1));
    return 2;
  }
}

static int image_free(lua_State *L)
{
  Image *imp = (Image*)luaL_checkudata(L, 1, "imlib2.image");
  Image im = *imp;
  if(im)
  {
    imlib_context_set_image(im);
    imlib_free_image();
    *imp = NULL;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Not even the first image has been saved. What am I doing wrong? If I use only one save it works perfectly